# How to Display image using image path retrieved from database in React.js

Tags: reactjs, laravel, image, api, axios

Im trying to display an image using api axios , the api is retrieving the path image from database but the image is not loading

```
import axios from 'axios';
```

class Products extends Component {

```
state={
        products:[],
};

componentDidMount() {
    axios.get(`http://localhost/CraveByMarwa/public/api/products`)
      .then(res => {
        const products = res.data;
        this.setState({ products });
      })
  }

render() {
    return (
        <div>
<div className="block-section big-spacer">
<div className="container">
  <h3 className="section-title" data-aos="fade-up" style={{fontSize: 55, textAlign: 'center'}}>
    <span style={{color: 'rgba(209, 0, 0, 1)'}}>Plans &amp; Pricing
    </span>
  </h3>
</div>
<div className="container">
  <div className="row">
{ this.state.products.map(products =>
    <div className="col-md-4">
      <div className="block-img">
        <div className="flip-card">
          <div className="flip-card-inner">
            <div className="flip-card-front">
              <img src={products.productImagePath} alt={products.title} style={{width: 300, height: 500}} />
```

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. Can you console log and show what is in products.productImagePath. Is it a path to your image file in server or is it a blob or is it any generated url?

Comment: @Darkshadow its showing for example :                                          
   productImagePath: "./css/image/thestandard.png"

Comment: @Darkshadow Any Idea? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to create an image file in the public folder and add the path to the database for ex: the database will be like 'image/123.png'